# database connection time expired issue

Tags: sql-server, database, networking, firewall

I have a server machine and four client machine for database connectivity.

I installed sqlexpress 2008 in server and one machine and all remaining systems, they have connected the database through the EMS (SQL Manager 2008 for SQL Server ).

The issue is that when I connect the database from that m/c which has sqlexpress 2008 then it gives "Timeout Expired"

But all remaining systems connect to server easily.

Why it gives an error for that particular system.

I didn't get any proper solution for this issue.

Comment: You sure you just don't have network problems? name lookup and ping works fine?

Comment: yes I am sure. because all remaining are working fine

Comment: Both systems (sql 2008 and client sql 2008 express) are on same service pack / Patch level ? You connect via TCP/IP regular? Checked any firewall settings? Or maybe you have any local firewall client on your desktop machines? And btw: Why you use sql express and not just install die EMS from the main product on a client desktop?

Comment: YvesR -> yes both are same service pack. I can access both system from each other by local connection and all remaining three computers are working smoothly with the same configuration. I already checked the firewalls, all client systems have same settings. Its our requirement to install sql server 2008 on server and EMS on client machines.

Comment: Hmm, well then I guess you have to use a tool like http://www.wireshark.org/ and listen on IP to see what happens when you connect if all settings are identical. Logical spoken: server is ok due the fact other clients works fine and there must be something else configured on your machine that don't work.

Comment: Thanks but I never used the wireshark. so can you more explain about this

Comment: Well, it is a big think to explain it at all, go look this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bazkLeY6b4 and after setup it and trace your connection between client and server. Maybe you find out more what happens then.

Comment: Ok I will check and then reply you

Comment: I checked connection through wireshark. the connection is proper but issue remains same

Comment: how do you connect to the server? tried ip address instead of the name? and server has an instance or you connect directly? Did you try setup a odbc sql server connection to test connection there for example if this work or timeout, too?

Comment: I am connecting the server with its name not IP. When I connecting with IP then its taking more time but connect.

Comment: To me it sounds more like a general network problem. try reinstall network device or relace it. Or reinstall tcp/ip stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what do you use to connect: Windows integrated security or SQL Server security?

And also, make sure you are connecting to the right instance of SQL Server on server machine (default instance doesn't need to specify the instance name, while for named instances you need to connect to \\

Hope this helps,

Bye

cghersi

Comment: Thanks for answer.                                            Before generating this problem it was working fine on all system without any error. This error suddenly generated and I increase the timeout for connection from 15 sec. to 30 sec., then it is connect but very slow and I can't the work on project with this connectivity. When this connection is established, the sessions of project got timeout. If you have any solution for this error then plz tell